# My Variable does not increment when i click a button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a button which changes the song playing in the background. i named the songs 0,1,2,3.ogg and put them inside my main directory. But it doesnt work after 1 time. so when its playing 0.ogg and i click, it changes. but after i click another time the var stays at 1 and the song doesnt change

i tried ++var and var++ and some other minor things

```
function SongChange(){
      var prefix = 0;
      var song = prefix + ".ogg";

      ++prefix;

      document.getElementById("audio").pause();
      document.getElementById("audio").setAttribute('src', song);
      document.getElementById("audio").load();
      document.getElementById("audio").play();
      console.log(prefix);
    }
```

Comment: Every time your function runs, `prefix` will *always* have the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call the function, `++prefix` increments `prefix` … but the **first** thing that happens when you run the function is that `var prefix = 0;` sets it to `0`!

Move `var prefix = 0;` outside the function, so it doesn't set the variable to `0` every time the function is called.

Comment: oh i see, i always had it on top or inside the function. makes sense now thank you. i thought i had to declare a variable first before i can write an value into it.

Comment: @LeonardoL. — In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), which you should be using, it is mandatory to declare variables. You just have to declare them in the scope you want them to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

When `SongChange` is run, the first thing is does is set prefix to 0. If prefix were 7 and you ran this method then it would:

1. Set prefix to 0
2. Play song 0
3. Increment prefix (setting it to 1)

No matter what the value of prefix is before you run the function, you're always going to play song 0

Instead, you need prefix to exist **outside** of your function:

```
var prefix = 0;

function SongChange() {
      ++prefix;
      var song = prefix + ".ogg";

      document.getElementById("audio").pause();
      document.getElementById("audio").setAttribute('src', song);
      document.getElementById("audio").load();
      document.getElementById("audio").play();
}
```

As well, you should check that `prefix` doesn't get too large:

```
var prefix = 0;

function SongChange() {
      ++prefix;

      if (prefix > 3)
            prefix = 0;

      var song = prefix + ".ogg";

      document.getElementById("audio").pause();
      document.getElementById("audio").setAttribute('src', song);
      document.getElementById("audio").load();
      document.getElementById("audio").play();
}
```

### Alternate solutions:

There are a lot of ways to make `prefix` persistent, but making it persistent is your main problem. You can:

#### Set it as a property on a static object (like a Function object)

```
function SongChange() {
  SongChange.prefix++;
  var song = SongChange.prefix + ".ogg";
  // ...
}
SongChange.prefix = 0;
```

```
function SongChange() {
  window.prefix++;
  var song = window.prefix + ".ogg";
  // ...
}
window.prefix = 0;
```

#### Extract the previous prefix from the `<audio>` tag:

```
function SongChange() {
  var prefix = Number(document.getElementById("audio").src.split(".")[0]) || 0;
  prefix++;
  var song = prefix + ".ogg";
  // ...
}
```

#### Store prefix in LocalStorage

```
function SongChange() {
  var prefix = Number(localStorage.getItem("prefix")) || 0;
  prefix++;
  var song = prefix + ".ogg";
  localStorage.setItem("prefix", prefix);
  // ...
}
```

There are other options, but I'm sure you can get creative and figure them out.